# CodeIgniter AJAX Call to undefined function ajax_response()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem in ajax_response
I have a script like this in my controller

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller
{

    public function get_data($op_produk = '')
    {
        if ($op_produk=='' || $op_id=='')
        {
        ajax_response('ID Voucher tidak benar.', 'failed');
        }
       
    }
}
```

and after I execute in my URL like this domain.com/get_data

it should display a message like this

```
{"status":false,"message":"ID Voucher tidak benar.","alert":"failed"}
```

But I got this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function ajax_response()

Filename: controllers/Ajax.php

Line Number: 23

Backtrace:
```

what this problem? I try to use in Cpanel and this working but in webuzo I got the error message?

Comment: where is the function ajax_response()? Are you just looking for a way to output the response?

Comment: where `ajax_response` defined?

Comment: @Kinglish yes.. i want to show output response

Comment: @DevsiOdedra - it's cant be defined, the error says so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicity set your output for that - which means you create an array and then echo it through json_encode. To output an ajax response like that in codeigniter, it's best to use the Output class.

```
public function get_data($op_produk = '') {
  if ($op_produk == '' || $op_id == '') {
  $this->output
     ->set_content_type('application/json')
     ->set_output(json_encode(array(
       'message' => 'ID Voucher tidak benar.', 
       'alert' => 'failed', 
       'status' => 'false')));
       exit;
  }
}
```